# Appcelerator: Proper Way Automatically Dismiss Keyboard

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

I'm writing an app using Titanium. I want to be able to automatically dismiss the keyboard anytime something outside of the text field is clicked. I have yet to find an elegant solution for this issue.

Couple things that I've thought about, but am still looking for a better solution:

1. Assign event listeners to basically everything else present in the view, and dismiss the keyboard (using `textField.blur()`). I want to avoid this since it results in a LOT of code just to dismiss the keyboard. Also, if I end up adding anything else to the view, I'll have to add a click listener to that object as well, so it's not very maintainable.
2. Create a large transparent view, and have it take up the entire screen. Place it directly beneath the text field and add to it one click listener on that which will dismiss the keyboard. This is a better solution than #1, but still isn't great because I've had a lot of trouble getting zIndexes to work properly. It's also inefficient for my purposes because I've got views with a specific width and height that encapsulate text fields. I've used these for the sake of code simplicity and I re-use them throughout my application.
3. I've tried adding a listener for the "blur" event for the text field but that doesn't seem to get fired appropriately.

That's about it. I'm sort of at a loss. The zIndexing also behaves strangely on the iPhone, and I haven't tried on Android yet. Also, as I mentioned above, many of the text fields I use are encapsulated within small views with set widths/heights-- so I think that will affect the functionality of Z-indexes.

So the root question is: What's the best way to dismiss a keyboard whenever *anything* outside the text field that's in focus is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct the click event propagates through all views and windows therefore your #1 option could be modified to check for clicks on the bottom most layer (view or window), check for its source then decide what to do.

Comment: Looks like this is going to be my best solution. I have some places where I have a window popping over another window, so I'll have to add 2 listeners in that case. The only part I don't like is that even if I have the source, I have to call blur() on the current focused text field, so I have to iterate through the views to find the right one.