# Appcelerator : Close all textfield's keyboard without knowing which is open

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

It's possible to hide the keyboard of a textfield, without knowing which textfield have the focus active?

For example, if i have a **view** with 4 **textfields**, and a **button** to hide this view, i have to do this for be sure to close all keyboards (on the click event of the button)

```
textfield1.blur();
textfield2.blur(); 
textfield3.blur();
textfield4.blur();
```

Or save in a global variable the reference of the textfield that is currently open, with the help of the focus/blur event.

- The same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001774/appcelerator-proper-way-automatically-dismiss-keyboard)
- Interesting doc that i found : [endEditing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a dependency by using a somewhat outdated module you could try this:

Create a new file and call it whatever you want, I used `yourview.js` for this example. Paste the following code in it:

```
module.exports = {
    view: Ti.UI.createView({
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#ddd',
        button: Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'blur all textfields' }),
        textfields: [
            Ti.UI.createTextField({ value: 'first' }),
            Ti.UI.createTextField({ value: 'second' }),
            Ti.UI.createTextField({ value: 'third' }),
            Ti.UI.createTextField({ value: 'fourth' }),
        ]
    }),
    construct: function()
    {
        var self = this;

        self.view.button.addEventListener('click', function(){
            for(var i in self.view.textfields)
                self.view.textfields[i].blur();
        });

        // Add textfields to view
        for(var i in self.view.textfields)
            self.view.add(self.view.textfields[i]);

        // Add button to view
        self.view.add(self.view.button);

        return self.view;   
    }
};
```

The `yourview.js` file contains everything you want to show in that particular view. The construct function will add everything together when you're going to use the view in your Window object which will look like this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    yourview: require('namespace/ui/yourview').construct()
});

// Add your reference to the scope of the Window object
win.add(win.yourview);

win.open();

// If you want to get the value of the textfields in this scope just use it like this:
Ti.API.info(win.yourview.textfields[0].value);
```

This way you have everything you want in separate files :)

Tested and works in iOS 9.3 simulator with Ti.5.4.0 SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But to do this, i would change almost completely the app, which is very complex. It seems to me still a method a bit too elaborate, strange that there isn't a simpler method for this function.

Comment: A more simpler method would be creating a global array variable in your .js file and add the textfields in there. Then you could iterate through them like I did in my example. It's simple but not the most beautiful tbh.

Comment: Agreed. This is the approach that we follow all of the time. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom module like Ti.Keyboard:

https://github.com/manojdcoder/keyboard

Comment: Thanks, but the module is outdated

Comment: Did you look into the source code? It's just a wrapper for the mentioned native method:

```
    -(id)hide:(id)args
    {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
            UIView *topView = window.rootViewController.view;
            [topView endEditing:YES];
        });
    }